# Why does a piston oscillate at a much lower frequency than a standing wave within a tube?

Tags: thermodynamics, acoustics

I have a thermoacoustic engine, with a stack producing sound waves - the piston is attached to the open end of the tube, but why does it oscillate at a much lower frequency than the sound wave itself. Friction definitely isnt the answer, friction has been characterized to be very very low.
Is there a qualitative explanation for this observed phenomenon ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The mass of the piston plays a large role. The heavier the piston, the slower it will oscillate. The sound is heating the gas and the temperature change occurs at a rate much slower than the acoustic frequency.

Comment: How do i add that quantitatively